# How to detect menu button press in TVOS app using TVJS

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvjs

I need to know when a document(screen) is popped off the stack in an Apple tvOS app. I thought detecting the Menu button press would be the simplest way, but I'm using TVJS and have not been able to figure out how to write the event handler.

Please help me write an event handler that will fire on document removal, menu button press or offer an alternative solution.

Comment: Are you using a `menuBarTemplate`? If so, how does the `menuItem`, you want to attach the event to, look like? Post a bit of code so we can help you better :)

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the event `unload` - it's triggered whenever a page disappears after being popped from the stack:

```
doc.addEventListener("unload", Presenter.onUnload.bind(Presenter));

[...]

onUnload: function(event) {
   console.log("onUnload");
},
```

Comment: Does it work for the root template too? Where did you find all the supported events (official documentation is awful)?

Comment: Root template? Like the last one closing when leaving your app? Honestly, I have no idea... But for that you could use the `App.onSuspend` event in your main App.js. Not sure if I know "all" supported events - I mainly grabbed them from different examples spread over the internet. Plus some earlier experience dealing with old aTV (speak PlexConnect).

Comment: The onSuspend event sounds about right. Thanks. Anything on the other question, anywhere with a more complete documentation?

Comment: No, sorry, no more complete documentation. Added some remarks about that in my earlier comment already. :-D

Comment: Hmm, sounds promising, I'll check out the unload event on the nav document.

Answer (score 0):

There is such thing of a handler for `onDocumentRemoval` or similar. What you can do, instead, is create a global `select` handler:

```
doc.addEventListener("select", self.doThing.bind(self));
```

And then check if the fired event comes from one of the buttons used to remove an element of the stack (let's suppose those buttons have a class named `delete`:

```
doThing: function(event){
    var element = event.target;
    if (element.getAttribute("class").contains("delete")){
       //enter code here
    }
```

---

EDIT 1:

I found the [possible events the TVMLKit handles](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLKit/Reference/TVViewElement_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/TVElementUpdateType) (I know it is in Swift/Objective-C, but the events are the same):

> TVElementTypePlay
>
> - A play event has been dispatched.
>
> TVElementTypeSelect
>
> - A select event has been dispatched.
>
> TVElementTypeHoldSelect
>
> - A hold event has been dispatched.
>
> TVElementTypeHighlight
>
> - A highlight event has been dispatched.
>
> TVElementTypeChange
>
> - A change event has been dispatched.

Those events are only attachable to a template as far as I could test. I guessed the `change` event would be perfect if I could attach it to the `navigationDocument` to listen for changes, but those two options won't work and both fire errors:

Attached to the global:

```
navigationDocument.addEventListener("change", function(event){console.log(event)});
```

Attached to the documents array:

```
navigationDocument.documents.addEventListener("change", function(event){console.log(event)});
```

There is no built-in method for those above to listen for any change. The event, though, will work on a template listening to internal changes. But it won't fire when the template is `pushed` to or `popped` from the stack.

I am guessing you will need to re-design your app in order to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is when a user presses the 'Menu' button on the Apple remote it removes a document from the stack. How do I know when that button has been pressed? I really just need to know when a document has been removed from the stack. Is there an event I can listen for?

Comment: @Corgalore Updated the post with some bad news